# input and print in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, time-complexity

We know that `print` statement has been deprecated in Python 3, but we also know that `print()` function is present in both. Which one of them is faster and how does the deprecating helps in the aspect of the function?

Same problem with the `input()` function, how does the deprecation of `raw_input` helps in determining the speed of `input()` in Python 2 and Python 3?

Edit : Comparison based on iPython and iPython3 respectively.

This is iPython.

```
In [1]: %%time
   ...: print("Hello World!")
   ...: 
Hello World!
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 16.2 µs
```

This is iPython3.

```
In [1]: %%time
   ...: print("Hello World!")
   ...: 
Hello World!
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 61 µs
```

Python3 seems to be slower!

Comment: I don't think it's all about performance, more about providing a more uniform way of printing and getting input.

Comment: But the speed *is* affected.

Comment: What do you mean *"degraded"*? Deprecated? Programs where performance is critical generally don't `print` at all, so I doubt this was a big concern in the development.

Comment: Maybe it is (even though I don't think a single test can lead to a satisfying conclusion in a case of something that measures in µs, you should do something like, 100/1000 tests and calculate the average timing). And I do agree with @jonrsharpe, when performance is an issue, usually you don't print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 made `print` a *function*, rather than a *statement*; calling a function will always add some overhead. Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to look at the bytecode generated in the two versions backs this up:

**Script**:

```
def print_item(item):
    print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dis
    dis.dis(print_item)
```

**2.7.10**:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

**3.4.3**:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, over 1,000 iterations in both versions, using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), I actually saw slightly slower performance in 2.x (2.46s vs. 2.30s). In practice, this is irrelevant, as when performance is critical **you don't `print` at all**.

Note that you can use `from __future__ import print_function` to get 3.x-style printing in 2.x. For more information on why `print` was made a function, see [PEP-3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/).

---

You also mention `input` - any performance differences between implementations in 2.x and 3.x is **completely irrelevant**, as the time spent waiting for some lumbering meatsack to type their characters and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> is going to be *orders of magnitude* more than the time spent passing it to your code as a string. That being said, you can use `dis` again to demonstrate that `raw_input` in 2.x and `input` in 3.x generate the same bytecode.

Answer (score 4):

Making `print()` a function is more about providing convenience.

1. With `print()` being a function, it is possible to replace the function by doing `def print(...)` or importing a new function from somewhere else.
2. You can do this:

   ```
   [print(i) for i in range(10)] # seems a bit impractical, though
   ```

   or

   ```
   f = lambda x: print(x)
   ```

   You can't do that with a `print` statement.
3. The `print()` function looks like this:

   ```
   def print(*args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None)
       ...
   ```

   - `args`: positional arguments whose values will be printed out.
   - `sep`: the separator, which will be printed between arguments.
   - `end`: the ending text, which will be printed after all of the arguments have been output.
   - `file`: the file object to which the output will be sent.

   So you can do

   ```
   print(*['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], sep=", ", end="\nAll values printed")
   # outputs ->
   a, b, c, d
   All values printed
   ```

   but you can't do the same with `print` statement. Yes you can write some code to do what the function is doing, but like I said, `print()` function is a little more convenient than its statement counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2,

```
%timeit print 'foo'
```

is only very marginally faster (8.97 vs 9.06 us) than

```
from __future__ import print_statement
%timeit print('foo')
```

In Python 3, that time goes up to 11 us, which puts Python 3 at less than 20% slower than Python 2. This seems to agree with the results that people have found [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/272bao/python_34_slow_compared_to_27_whats_your_mileage/) when running the entire PyStone benchmark suite.

TLDR: Python 3 is just slower than Python 2 - nothing to do with the print statement becoming a function

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of answers about `print` .

About `input()` / `raw_input()` function in python 2.x and python 3.x .

In python 2.x , input() is slightly different from raw_input()

1. **input()** - this function in python 2.x actually evaluates the input and then returns it . An example -

   ```
   >>> input('Hello : ')
   Hello : 2<3
   True
   ```
2. **raw_input()** - Whereas `raw_input()` does not evaluate the input and rather provides the input as a string. An example -

   ```
   >>> raw_input('Hello : ')
   Hello : 2<3
   '2<3'
   ```

---

In python 3.x , the `raw_input()` function was renamed to `input()` , I am guessing they felt that there was no need for an `input()` function that provides the result after evaluating it (I never saw a use for it either , wonder if anyone did really use it)

Comment: To get the functionality of old `input()` one can use `eval(input())` (bad!) or `ast.literal_eval(input())` - this is obviously a much safer default, as you actually have to be trying to do this rather than getting bitten unintentionally.